# Terraform: Create Azure VM with existing Image. Result: 400 Bad Request "osProfile" is not allowed

Tags: azure, image, terraform, virtual-machine, devops

```
 # Configure the Azure provider
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "~> 3.0.2"
    }
    random = {
      source  = "hashicorp/random"
      version = "~>3.0"
    }
  }

  required_version = ">= 1.1.5"
}

provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}
/* 
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
  name     = "tf_accCloudResourceGroup"
  location = "westeurope"
} */
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
  location = var.resource_group_location
  name     = "${random_pet.prefix.id}-rg"
}


resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "my_terraform_network" {
  name                = "${random_pet.prefix.id}-vnet"
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
}

# Create subnet
resource "azurerm_subnet" "my_terraform_subnet" {
  name                 = "${random_pet.prefix.id}-subnet"
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.my_terraform_network.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.0.1.0/24"]
}

# Create public IPs
resource "azurerm_public_ip" "my_terraform_public_ip" {
  name                = "${random_pet.prefix.id}-public-ip"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  allocation_method   = "Dynamic"
}

# Create Network Security Group and rules
resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "my_terraform_nsg" {
  name                = "${random_pet.prefix.id}-nsg"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name

  security_rule {
    name                       = "RDP"
    priority                   = 1000
    direction                  = "Inbound"
    access                     = "Allow"
    protocol                   = "*"
    source_port_range          = "*"
    destination_port_range     = "3389"
    source_address_prefix      = "*"
    destination_address_prefix = "*"
  }
  security_rule {
    name                       = "web"
    priority                   = 1001
    direction                  = "Inbound"
    access                     = "Allow"
    protocol                   = "Tcp"
    source_port_range          = "*"
    destination_port_range     = "80"
    source_address_prefix      = "*"
    destination_address_prefix = "*"
  }
}

# Create network interface
resource "azurerm_network_interface" "my_terraform_nic" {
  name                = "${random_pet.prefix.id}-nic"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name

  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "my_nic_configuration"
    subnet_id                     = azurerm_subnet.my_terraform_subnet.id
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
    public_ip_address_id          = azurerm_public_ip.my_terraform_public_ip.id
  }
}

# Connect the security group to the network interface
resource "azurerm_network_interface_security_group_association" "example" {
  network_interface_id      = azurerm_network_interface.my_terraform_nic.id
  network_security_group_id = azurerm_network_security_group.my_terraform_nsg.id
}

# Create storage account for boot diagnostics
resource "azurerm_storage_account" "my_storage_account" {
  name                     = "diag${random_id.random_id.hex}"
  location                 = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name      = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "LRS"
}


# Create virtual machine
resource "azurerm_windows_virtual_machine" "main" {
  name                  = "${var.prefix}-vm"
  admin_username        = "azureuser"
  admin_password        = random_password.password.result
  location              = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name   = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  network_interface_ids = [azurerm_network_interface.my_terraform_nic.id]
  size                  = "Standard_DS1_v2"
  source_image_id       = "/subscriptions/9c28955b-a2e9-411a-a3bf-b9c4c53f531e/resourceGroups/myGalleryRG/providers/Microsoft.Compute/galleries/myGallery/images/ACC_base_image/versions/1.0.0"

  os_disk {
    name                 = "myOsDisk"
    caching              = "ReadWrite"
    storage_account_type = "Premium_LRS"
  }

  boot_diagnostics {
    storage_account_uri = azurerm_storage_account.my_storage_account.primary_blob_endpoint
  }
}
/* 
# Install IIS web server to the virtual machine
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "web_server_install" {
  name                       = "${random_pet.prefix.id}-wsi"
  virtual_machine_id         = azurerm_windows_virtual_machine.main.id
  publisher                  = "Microsoft.Compute"
  type                       = "CustomScriptExtension"
  type_handler_version       = "1.8"
  auto_upgrade_minor_version = true

  settings = <<SETTINGS
    {
      "commandToExecute": "powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted Install-WindowsFeature -Name Web-Server -IncludeAllSubFeature -IncludeManagementTools"
    }
  SETTINGS
} */
# Generate random text for a unique storage account name
resource "random_id" "random_id" {
  keepers = {
    # Generate a new ID only when a new resource group is defined
    resource_group = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  }

  byte_length = 8
}

resource "random_password" "password" {
  length      = 20
  min_lower   = 1
  min_upper   = 1
  min_numeric = 1
  min_special = 1
  special     = true
}

resource "random_pet" "prefix" {
  prefix = var.prefix
  length = 1
}
```

**This code receives in an error, a 400 Bad Request**
[image: Error]

And the cause is, from the microsoft documentation, that the image contains a username & password, but I cannot leave them empty:[image]

Creating the VM with the CLI or the portal does work properly. Can anybody help me? This is my origin image:
[image]

Thank you very much and best regards,
Markus

Comment: Is that a specialized image you are using from the Gallery? How was the image created. I run into the same problem with specialized images created by Packer.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. This is an own created image, like the Image I added

Answer (score 0):

> I tried to provision a Linux VM from the Image created from the existing VM and I was able successfully run the terraform commands.

To achieve this configuration, we need to follow few steps before creating the image.

**Image creation can be done in two ways**.

1. Directly from the portal services called VM Images.
2. By capturing the direct image from VM

Here to achieve the required configuration I followed step 2.

**Procedure to create a Image from VM**.

- Provision a linux VM for your choice using terraform or directly from the portal.
- Once it's done, we need to deallocate the VM or stop running the VM to capture the Image of VM.

Remaining steps should be followed as mentioned below.

[image]

[image]

As per query you created Image by selecting `option 1` in **Share image to azure compute gallery** which in resulting the error mentioned in query.

Once creation of Image was done make note of `Image name` and `resource group name`  accordingly.

For the VM to be created from the image created, the terraform script goes as follows.

My **main.tf** :

```
provider  "azurerm" {

features {}

subscription_id  =  "xxxxxx"

client_id  =  "xxxxxxxx"

tenant_id  =  "xxxxxxxx"

client_secret  =  "xxxxxxxxx"

}

  
  



data  "azurerm_image"  "search" {

name  =  "demovk-vm-imagevk"

resource_group_name  =  "demorgvk"

}

  

output  "image_id" {

value  =  "/subscriptions/000000000000000000/resourceGroups/demorgvk/providers/Microsoft.Compute/images/demovk-vm-imagevk"

}

  



data  "azurerm_resource_group"  "main" {

name  =  "demorgvk"

}

  


resource  "azurerm_subnet"  "internal" {

name  =  "RG-Terraform-snet-in"

virtual_network_name  =  "RG-OPT-QA-Vnet"

resource_group_name  =  "${data.azurerm_resource_group.main.name}"

address_prefixes  =  ["10.100.2.0/24"]

}

  



resource  "azurerm_network_security_group"  "main" {

name  =  "RG-QA-Test-Dev-NSG"

location  =  "${data.azurerm_resource_group.main.location}"

resource_group_name  =  "${data.azurerm_resource_group.main.name}"

  

security_rule {

name  =  "allow_SSH"

description  =  "Allow SSH access"

priority  =  100

direction  =  "Inbound"

access  =  "Allow"

protocol  =  "Tcp"

source_port_range  =  "*"

destination_port_range  =  "22"

source_address_prefix  =  "*"

destination_address_prefix  =  "*"

}

}

  



resource  "azurerm_network_interface"  "main" {

name  =  "NIC"

location  =  "${data.azurerm_resource_group.main.location}"

resource_group_name  =  "${data.azurerm_resource_group.main.name}"

//network_security_group_id = "${azurerm_network_security_group.main.id}"

  

ip_configuration {

name  =  "nicconfig"

subnet_id  =  "${azurerm_subnet.internal.id}"

private_ip_address_allocation  =  "Static"

private_ip_address  =  "${cidrhost("10.100.2.16/24", 4)}"

}

}

  



  
resource  "azurerm_virtual_machine"  "vm" {

name  =  "Demovkvm"

location  =  "${data.azurerm_resource_group.main.location}"

resource_group_name  =  "${data.azurerm_resource_group.main.name}"

network_interface_ids  =  ["${azurerm_network_interface.main.id}"]

vm_size  =  "Standard_DS12_v2"

delete_os_disk_on_termination  =  true

delete_data_disks_on_termination  =  true

  

storage_image_reference {

id  =  "${data.azurerm_image.search.id}"

}

  

storage_os_disk {

name  =  "AZLXDEVOPS01-OS"

caching  =  "ReadWrite"

create_option  =  "FromImage"

managed_disk_type  =  "Standard_LRS"

}

  

os_profile {

computer_name  =  "APPVM"

admin_username  =  "adminuser"

admin_password  =  "Cssladmin#2019"

}

  

os_profile_linux_config {

disable_password_authentication  =  false

}

}
```

**Output**:

[image]

[image]

By this way we can create a VM from existing Image.